# LG L5 E612 Random Restart Problem

Tags: boot-loop, lg, lg-optimus-l5

I have an LG Optimus L5 (LG-E612) that has been acting up since five days ago. I would like to wipe device clean and do not mind if I lose data I have on device, however, I unable to do this.

**Observable problems:**

- Device randomly restarts and subsequently ends up in state it was in when I first noticed problem---on December 25
- An attempt to uninstall apps the normal way results in immediate device reboot
- An attempt to uninstall apps via adb results in immediate device reboot
- Factory reset fails

**Configuration details are as follows:**

```
Android version: 4.0.3
Baseband version: MSM7225A-1-AA
Kernel version: 3.0.8-perf
Build number: IML74K
Software version: V10b-NOV-12-2012
```

**This is what I have tried so far:**

1. Factory reset

   - Factory reset via 'Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset > Reset phone > Erase everything' fails---nothing happens
   - Factory reset using hardware keys combination(Volume- + Power + Home) fails---mobile device reboots after five seconds
2. Fastboot

   - Attempting to erase seemingly problematic partitions (cache; userdata) results in immediate reboot
3. ADB

   - 'adb reboot recovery' results in device reboot after five seconds
4. KDZ Updater

   - [I have attempted flashing](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191698)... flashing process appears successful but problem still persists
5. Official LG Software Updater Tool

   - This was probably the last straw. I hooked up phone via usb, in debugging + PC Suite mode... this was a success but problem is still there

PS: I tried asking for [help on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/optimus-l3-l5-l7-l9-ii/general/flash-clean-constantly-restarting-t2986370) when I initially noticed problem, but nothing useful has come out of that thread.

**Update #1: Observations Whilst in Safe Mode**

When I boot device in Safe Mode (Power on and then pressing Volume-& Volume+ together), random restart behaviour diminishes. I can even uninstall apps. I even have full root access. However, problem resurfaces the moment I reboot device---the installed apps pop right back...

Is there anything I can do to permanently clean up and fix device?

**Update #2: Manual data purge in Safe Mode**

In a desperate attempt to delete all apps, I manually ran `rm` commands on `/data` and `/cache`... still no luck. Device returns to previous state after rebooting. I believe it is safe to say I have completely run out of ideas here...

Comment: What I do not understand is how the apps are being restored when I explicitly purge then. Running mobile device in Safe Mode would have been an option if only I could run apps I use often...